# Hack slider div position with CSS? (Squarespace template Forte)

Tags: css, slider, gallery, squarespace

I have a question about this page I have built with Squarespace (template Forte): https://joyce-kozloff.squarespace.com/new-gallery-3 (this is not really a Squarespace question, more of a general CSS/JS hack question)

I've been trying to find a way to add general descriptive text on this page, as there is no option to do so in the template.

As a possible solution I thought I would set the first slide ti be an empty PNG and have the project description text underneath. This would work perfectly if the descriptive text would be automatically snapped up by default, instead of you needing to hover over the image.

The first slide div has a unique ID, so I've tried doing this:

```
#yui_3_17_2_1_1423251233094_294 .image-detail-wrapper {top: 0px !important}
```

But to no avail. I would be so grateful if anyone could suggest a way to raise the image-detail-wrapper div to the top of the content area, through CSS and/or javascript.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

```
#fullscreenBrowser .slideshow.strip .image-detail-wrapper {top: 0;background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,0);color: white;}
```

Is this the kind of effect you were looking for? The text overlayed on the image?